# LDAP Bind issues with ticket from Kerberos using GSSAPI

Tags: authentication, active-directory, ldap, kerberos, gssapi

I have been trying to make an application which needs to bind to LDAP server using GSSAPI using the ticket provided by the Kerberos server. I am using Novell's JLDAP library for this purpose.

I am able to get a ticket from the authentication server but when I try to bind to the Service Server(LDAP in my case ), I get  **GSSException: Major Status: (589824, Invalid token was supplied), Minor Status: (0, Unknown error)**
 and the bind fails.

The AS(Authentication Server) and SS(Service Server(LDAP server)), both are behind a single proxy.
In this case, do they need mutual authentication?

I not sure but it seems my java code is not able to get/recognize/decrypt the token recieved from the AS(Authentication Server).
I am providing the mechanism name as "**GSSAPI**" in the SASL bind method of Novell's LDAPConnection.java

Did anyone face this kind of trouble? What would be the cause and probable solutions for this? Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Have you [configured eDirectory to support GSSAPI](https://www.netiq.com/documentation/edir88/edir88/data/bs3o4x0.html)?

Errors for GSAPPI show in the ndsd.log file on the eDirectory server.
You can also enable +LDAP and +NMAS trace in ndstrace to see all communications for GSAPPI.

[This may also be helpful](http://www.novell.com/communities/node/2502/establishing-cross-realm-trust-between-active-directory-and-novell-kdc).